# Is using FastAPI with sync threads a good practice for a high scale application?

Tags: python, multithreading, fastapi, python-multithreading, gil

I'm using FastAPI with non-`async` endpoints running over gunicorn with multiple workers, from the `uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker` class as suggested [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/server-workers/). Latley, I noticed high latency in some of our endpoints during times in the day our application is busier than usual. I started to investigate it and I figured out that concurrency in our app doesn't work as we expect.

Let's say I have this FastAPI application (main.py) with the following endpoint

```py
app = FastAPI()
logger = logging.getLogger()

@app.get("/")
def root():
    logger.info(f"Running on {os.getpid()}")
    time.sleep(3600)
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

and I run `gunicorn` with the following cmd:

```
gunicorn main:app --workers 4 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

When I send to the server five requests, they all get to the same worker except the last one, instead of running in parallel over all workers:

```
INFO:root:Running on 643
INFO:root:Running on 643
INFO:root:Running on 643
INFO:root:Running on 643
INFO:root:Running on 642
```

If I turn the endpoint into `async`, every request will be handled on a different worker (the last one will be holded).
I know that when using non-async endpoint, FastAPI uses AnyIO threads to handle the requests, the default value for maximum threads is 40. When I try to lower this limit to 2 threads for example using the suggestion [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/4221#issuecomment-982260467), only the first two requests are being handled while the rest are waiting (even though I still have 4 workers!)

That's bad because both not using all our resources and suffering from python threading problems due to GIL on the same worker.

Is there a way to overcome those problems without turning to `async` endpoints?

Comment: While [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) may not answer your question, it might give you a different perspective/solution to the problem you are faced with.

Comment: Are you sending your requests concurrently to the server or in series?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you are sending the requests ? I've tried reproducing your issue but when sending a few requests the same 4 workers - 2 threads setup, requests are dispatched among 3 workers and handled in batches of 6 (I'm not sure what the 4th worker does, but it is probably left available so that i can handle incoming requests)